# Index In SQL Server 2012

Tags: sql, indexing, sql-server-2012

[image]

I have this table in my database where `HusbandPersonId` and `WifePersonId` are foreign keys to another table called `Person`, and the start/end date refer when the marriage start and when it ends.

And I have this query :

```
SELECT
   DISTINCT A.WifePersonId
FROM
   Couple A
   INNER JOIN Couple B
      ON A.WifePersonId = B.WifePersonId
      AND A.HusbandPersonId <> B.HusbandPersonId
      AND A.StartDate < B.EndDate
      AND A.EndDate > B.StartDate;
```

which returns any wife that is married to more than one person at same time.

Now I would like to add an index to improve the speed of search of this query.

Which index would be the best and what is the execution plan of the query before and after the index has been added ?

This is a request in homework and I search too much but I didn't find any helpful topic

Can anyone help on this ?

Comment: @ErikE Can you Help in this :D

Comment: Not sure what the aim of the homework is, really. But if you have a database that's populated with a realistic amount of data, and run the query, the system will *suggest* indexes. These suggestions should be taken with a pinch of salt, but can be a useful starting point.

Answer (score 1):

General indexing rules suggest including all fields in your join condition. The order of these fields may have an affect. Again, general rules suggest ordering the fields in order of increasing cardinality (# of unique values for each field).

So you might try:

```
CREATE INDEX Couple__multi ON Couple(StartDate, EndDate, WifePersonId, HusbandPersonId)
```

This assumes that the # of distinct start/end dates is less than the number of unique wife/husband PersonIds.

These rules are basically Indexing 101 type things. Most of the time they will get you an acceptable level of performance. It depends highly on your data and application if this is sufficient for your purposes.

Personally, I have not thought much of the SQL Performance Analyzer-suggested indexes, but I last took a serious look at them in SQL2005. I'm sure there has been some improvement since.

Hope this helps.